# Printing BST sideway from top to bottom

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search-tree

I have a question related to BST printing. I could print the tree sideways using different tree printing algorithm. However, I always print the tree from left to right. So is there any way to print the tree upside down? I saw some idea about using XY but I don't want to do that in console, so is there any different method to achieve the same thing?

Edit: For example, I have inputs as L, M, R, T, S, G, Y, S, D, E, C, A. Using inorder traversal, I got this input

```
              Y
          T
              S
       R
    M
 L
    G
          E
       D
          C
             A
```

What I want is the same thing as rotate this 90 degree to the right, and L should be on top followed by the others.

Edit 2: Here is the code using Level Order to print the tree, however, I am not sure how to put the format to display to be what I wanted.

```
queue<TreeNode*> q;

while(node != NULL)
{
    cout << node->data << " " << endl;
    if (node->left)
        q.push(node->left);
    if(node->right)
        q.push(node->right);
    if(!q.empty())
    {
        node = q.front();
        q.pop();
    }
    else
        node = NULL;
}
```

Comment: does the implementation of the tree have a link to their parent nodes? If so I think that it should be possible to do this. If not then you could run a normal print and store those values in an array and then traverse it backwards (that would be pretty inefficient though).

Comment: What do you mean by "upside down"?

Comment: Yes there is left and right pointers.

Comment: Upside down mean printing the tree from top to bottom like the actually tree.

Comment: @Spincel I was wondering if there is a pointer tot he `parent` of the node as in if I do `child->parent` do I get the node 1 level closer to the root node.

Comment: Your question would be a lot more clear if you showed some examples of inputs with the corresponding desired outputs (and maybe also some not-desired outputs).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [Breadth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) ?

Comment: I tried that, however, I am not sure how I can display the data from the queue to be exact as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How would you do this by hand? That's the real question; the C++ code is just writing down all the steps. My approach would be to print the top node `L` in the center, so with 40 spaces in front of it. The second level nodes, I'd print with 20 (`G`) and then 40 (`M`) spaces in front of the. The third level, I'd print 10 spaces, then `C`, then 20 spaces, etc...

I.e. at depth D, I have 2<sup>D</sup> elements that I need to print, so each of them gets `linewidth>>D` width.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. It prints very well,maybe its not perfectly symmetrical.
little description:

- 1st function - prints level by level (root lv -> leaves lv)
- 2nd function - distance from the beginning of new line
- 3rd function - prints nodes and calculates distance between two prints;

---

```
void Tree::TREEPRINT()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= treeHeight(getroot())){
        printlv(i);
        i++;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Tree::printlv(int n){
    Node* temp = getroot();
    int val = pow(2, treeHeight(root) -n+2);
    cout << setw(val) << "";
    prinlv(temp, n, val);
}

void Tree::dispLV(Node*p, int lv, int d)
{
    int disp = 2 * d;
    if (lv == 0){
        if (p == NULL){

            cout << " x ";
            cout << setw(disp -3) << "";
            return;
        }
        else{
            int result = ((p->key <= 1) ? 1 : log10(p->key) + 1);
            cout << " " << p->key << " ";
            cout << setw(disp - result-2) << "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (p == NULL&& lv >= 1){
            dispLV(NULL, lv - 1, d);
            dispLV(NULL, lv - 1, d);
        }
        else{
            dispLV(p->left, lv - 1, d);
            dispLV(p->right, lv - 1, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
50-28-19-30-29-17-42-200-160-170-180-240-44-26-27
```

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtPXY.png